# Get Google Search to display full page titles

Tags: google-search

With this search: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=+cannot+be+applied+%22bool+and+bool%22

I get this result: [image: screen cap]

There's a ton of white space off to the right side. But the first few links don't actually answer my question — which I would have known if I could see the entire title! But instead it gets trimmed and I have to click through to the page to see the full post title.

It's annoying. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: In the case of the SO links you can at least hover over the link to get the full URL from which the full title is derived.

Answer (score 3):

There is no fix.

[Why Google Changes Your Titles in Search Results](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2342232/Why-Google-Changes-Your-Titles-in-Search-Results) by Jennifer Slegg, April 29, 2014.

Try using some extension for your browser.

Comment: "some extension" -- got anything beyond that?